# Getting value data-toggle radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble getting the value from a Bootstrap radio button field with data-toggle="wizard-radio".

```js
$('[data-toggle="wizard-radio"]').click(function() {
      wizard = $(this).closest('.wizard-card');
      wizard.find('[data-toggle="wizard-radio"]').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(wizard).find('[type="radio"]').removeAttr('checked');
      $(this).find('[type="radio"]').attr('checked', 'true');
});
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
  <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio" rel="tooltip" title="Selecteer deze optie als het een eengezinswoning betreft" name="mhb_type">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" value="House" name="mhb_type">
    <div class="icon">
       <i class="material-icons">home</i>
    </div>
    </label>
    <h6>Eengezinswoning</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

It can't get the value of radio button. Anyone any idea how to fix this?

Comment: can you add the html fragment containing the **wizard-card** class?

Comment: Your code is invalid in at least two ways: 1. `label` elements can not contain block level elements like `div`; 2. When I click Run code snippet, I immediately get an error.

Comment: Where is `.wizard-card`? And why are you searching for `[data-toggle="wizard-radio"]` again instead of using `this`? and why are you removing the `active` and then adding it again in the same code? And then you're doing the same to `radio`? Your code makes no sense. Also your HTML is invalid as the `label` tag cannot contain `div` as Mike mentioned. Explain what you're trying to do so we can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! I want to use images instead of radio buttons, that's why I added the <label>. Did not know you can't use <div> then.

The .wizard-card is in an upper <div>. I have no experience with javascript (only html and php)

Comment: try `$('[data-toggle="wizard-radio"]')` to `$('input[type="radio"]')`

Comment: If this is NOT a duplicate, please edit your question to reflect what OTHER things you are having trouble with, as stated it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to use Materials Icons with Bootstrap.

1. Place this in the `<head>` tag:

   ```
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/2.1.19/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   ```
2. Place this before the closing `</body>` tag:

   ```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   ```
3. Use a minimum of 2 Materials special classes for Bootstrap per element (usually its an `<i>`)

   ```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
   ```

   **`<i class="mdi mdi-home"></i>`**

   ```
   </button>
   ```

   Always use class `.mdi` and follow that with `.mdi-*` (*the name of icon)
4. There are some CSS rulesets that must be included as well. See the Demo.

The set of buttons are a slightly modified version of what you can find at [**Material Design Icons - Bootstrap**](https://materialdesignicons.com/bootstrap). I wrote the radio button styles myself because the styles offered by MDI wasn't very versatile. The Unicode used in the `content` properties can be found in the **[stylesheet](https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/2.1.19/css/materialdesignicons.min.css)**.

Most form controls have the value attribute available which can be set/get by the [jQuery **`.val()`** method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) or the [plain JavaScript property **`.value`**](https://plainjs.com/javascript/attributes/set-get-and-remove-properties-of-dom-elements-10/). While this holds true for the radio buttons, the `<button>` value is omitted from these particular `<button>`s to avoid repetition, so I opted to extract their text content instead with the [jQuery **`.text()`** method](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or the [plain JavaScript property **`.textContent`**](http://xahlee.info/js/js_textContent_innerHTML_innerText_nodeValue.html).

### Demo

```js
// Any click on <button> or :radio button call getActive()
$('button, :radio').on('click', getActive);

function getActive(e) {
  // Define V
  var V = '';
  // If the clicked node is a <button>, get its text
  if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
    V = $(this).text();
    /* Otherwise if the clicked node [type] is radio...
    || get its value
    */
  } else if (e.target.type === 'radio') {
    V = $(this).val();
    // If neither <button> nor :radio then quit
  } else {
    return;
  }
  // Display value/text of clicked node
  $('#out').val(V);
}
```

```css
.mdi::before {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 14px;
}

.btn .mdi::before {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

.btn-xs .mdi::before {
  font-size: 18px;
  top: 3px;
}

.btn-sm .mdi::before {
  font-size: 18px;
  top: 3px;
}

.dropdown-menu .mdi {
  width: 18px;
}

.dropdown-menu .mdi::before {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  left: -8px;
}

.nav .mdi::before {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle .mdi::before {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.breadcrumb .mdi::before {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

.breadcrumb a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.breadcrumb a:hover span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.alert .mdi::before {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.input-group-addon .mdi::before {
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}

.navbar-brand .mdi::before {
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.list-group-item .mdi::before {
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  left: -3px
}


/* Radio */

input,
label {
  font: inherit;
  font-weight: 900
}

.rad {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#off,
#on,
#stand,
#kick {
  display: none
}

#on::before {
  font-family: "Material Design Icons";
  content: '\F521';
}

#kick::before {
  font-family: "Material Design Icons";
  content: "\F82B";
}

#on::after {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Symbol";
  content: '\a0ON';
}

#kick::after {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Symbol";
  content: '\a0KIA!';
}

#on,
#kick {
  display: inline-block;
}

#off::before {
  font-family: "Material Design Icons";
  content: '\F522';
}

#stand::before {
  font-family: "Material Design Icons";
  content: '\F64B';
}

#off::after {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Symbol";
  content: '\a0OFF';
}

#stand::after {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Symbol";
  content: '\a0...';
}

#rad0:checked~#on,
#radA:checked~#kick {
  display: inline-block;
}

#rad0:checked~#off,
#radA:checked~#stand {
  display: none;
}

#rad1:checked~#off,
#radB:checked~#stand {
  display: inline-block;
}

#rad1:checked~#on,
#radB:checked~#kick {
  display: none;
}

#out {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="//cdn.materialdesignicons.com/2.1.19/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <main class='container'>
    <form id='UI'>
      <article class='row'>
        <section class="col-md-4 col-sm-offset-2">
          <fieldset class='form-group'>
            <legend class='group-label'>Bootstrap IV / Material-Design Icons</legend>
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="mdi mdi-home"> </i>Home
</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="mdi mdi-stack-overflow" title='SO'> </i>SO 
</button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="mid dropdown-item" href="#">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-language-javascript active" title='JavaScript'>
            JavaScript</i>
                </a>
                <a class="mid dropdown-item" href="#">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-language-css3" title='CSS3'>
            CSS3</i>
                </a>
                <a class="mid dropdown-item" href="#">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-language-html5" title='HTML5'>
            HTML5</i>
                </a>
              </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
    <i class="mdi mdi-yin-yang"> </i>Balance
</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
    <i class="mdi mdi-skull"> </i>BEWARE!
</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
    <i class="mdi mdi-radioactive"> </i>DANGER!
</button>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </section>

        <section class='col-md-6'>
          <output id='out'></output>
        </section>

        <section class="col-md-6">
          <fieldset class='form-group'>
            <legend>RadioGroupList</legend>
            <div class='form-control'>
              <input type="radio" id="rad0" name="radGrp0" class="rad" value='on'>
              <input type="radio" id="rad1" name="radGrp0" class="rad" value='off' checked>
              <label id='off' for="rad0"></label>
              <label id='on' for="rad1"></label>
            </div>
            <div class='form-control'>
              <input type="radio" id="radA" name="radGrp1" class="rad" value='ATTACK!'>
              <input type="radio" id="radB" name="radGrp1" class="rad" value='Meditate' checked>
              <label id='stand' for="radA"></label>
              <label id='kick' for="radB"></label>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </section>
      </article>
    </form>
  </main>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to get the value using active class like :

```
$('.choice.active input').val()
```